# Trigger jquery when 'Gravity Forms' input button is clicked

Tags: jquery, forms, wordpress, input, onclick

I've updated the question because it may because of gravity forms which is stopping a simple function from working. The reason I say this is because I've tried so many options (listed below) to trigger a jQuery function, and none of them work when they should.

I have a simple function below which 100% works...

```
var $contactButton  = $(".contact-slide a"),
    $contactSlide   = $("#horizon-slide");

function () {
    $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
};
```

Simple as it gets, but I'm trying to trigger this when my submit button gets clicked from a gravity from.

This is the wordpress gravity forms input markup...

```
<input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="button gform_button" value="Send" tabindex="7"></input>
```

These are all the scripts below that I've tried, but none of them run the function...

**Script One**

```
$("input#gform_submit_button_1").on('click', function () {
    $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
});
```

**Script Two**

```
$("input#gform_submit_button_1").click(function() {
    $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
});
```

**Script Three**

```
$("input#gform_submit_button_1").focus(function () {
    $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
});
```

**Script Four**

```
$("form#gform_1").submit(function(event) {
$contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
});
```

I've also tried...

```
return false;
```

and

```
return true;
```

on all of the scripts above, but none of them return the function. If I set the scripts to return false then the form does not submit, but if I set to return true, then form submits but the function does not run.

Why is this happening, I thought this would be basic stuff?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `return true;` instead of `false`

Comment: Your click function returns `false`. This prevents form submitting.

Comment: Tried this, and the form submits now but does not run the function

Answer (score 7):

Are you trying to have something run upon form submission? If you're using the AJAX submission method of the form you can use the [gform_confirmation_loaded](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_confirmation_loaded) event to run some JavaScript after the form is submitted.

```
$(document).on('gform_confirmation_loaded', function(e, form_id){
   if(form_id == 2) {
       $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
   }
});
```

It will run on every form submission so to specify the form, test the form_id parameter passed to the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contactInput.focus(function () {
    $contactSlide.stop().css("top","0");
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 0);
    return true;
});
```

Give it a try :)

Comment: It does not run the function, hmmm weird. I've been triple checking all my code but the script runs fine, but I think its something to do with ether the varible not working, but it should for sure, or because i'm using gravity forms, maybe thats interfering. Do you know a way I can do it via adding a onclick on the input? Thanks

Comment: I've tried it with out the variable and still not running the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can control it from the form submit if you have a form..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.6.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#forma").submit(function(event) {
       //do what ever you need to here
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form name="1stform" method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="misc" id="misc" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit 1st form"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Andres thanks for you answer, I tried your method but does not run the script. I tried both return false and true. Return false stops the form from submitting, but return true does run whats inside the function

Comment: There's an error in the code, it should be <form name="forma" method="post" action="/">